# Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get value" - get values using semantic ui for Multiple Selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, semantic-ui

I want to retrieve data from Multiple selection dropdown design of semantic ui (link given below).
The data is getting populated dynamically using javascript and ajax using a .js file.

```
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- semantic UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<form id="compare-form" class="ui form small">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="me-2 flex-fill" id="business_units" style="width:320px;">
                  <input type="hidden" name="business_unit">
                  <select name="business-unit" multiple="" class="ui loading fluid dropdown buclass" id="business_unit-data-box">
                      <!-- Dynamically populating options here using JS -->
                      <option id="business_unit-text" value="">Choose a business unit</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="me-3 flex-fill">
                <button name="Fetch SPs" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="fetchsp" style="width:120px;">
                    Fetch SPs
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I can see how to fetching of data when options are already available in HTML file using jquery like below:

```
$("#multi-select").dropdown("get value")
```

But since my options are loaded dynamically, this is not working and getting below error:

```
dropdown.js:364 Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get value"
    at Function.dropdownInterface (dropdown.js:364)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:373)
    at Function.each (VM84186 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (VM84186 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (dropdown.js:372)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:48)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (VM84186 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (VM84186 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

To make it easy, I have added a button after the 'select' dom element, and thinking of triggering an event using "click" (click event handler) but can't figure out how.

Update 2: dropdown is working and values are retrievable here [Working Dropdown Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dr_essen/oeakfth5/10/) but in my workspace, getting "get value" error as shown above.

Update 3: This is happenning in pycharm environment while I am using Django framework. If I write a simple HTML, it's working fine without any framework.

[Multiple Selection Dropdown link - Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#multiple-selection)

Comment: Its working fine with that code as well. You can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zdLn6u30/)

Comment: nothing is present in the alert box.

Comment: select some value first from dropdown then try .

Comment: your's is working. When I put the similar thing in my js, my webpage reloads again with some random link in the addressbar. When I put inside addEventListener('click', e=>{} with e.preventDefault(), page doesn't load and proceeds fine. But now I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get value"".

Comment: Can you replicate that behaviour in demo code ? Its difficult to suggest any solution without seeing actual behaviour .

Comment: replica: https://jsfiddle.net/dr_essen/oeakfth5/8/ - here it's working fine, but I am getting below errors:
dropdown.js:364 Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get value"
    at Function.dropdownInterface (dropdown.js:364)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:373)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)

Comment: Note: I am using semantic ui component with bootstrap 5.

Comment: @Swati, I just observed that with class names: *.ui.fluid.dropdown*, dropdown is working but with *[name="skills set"]*, getting error:  *Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown(...) is not a function*

Comment: You might be having some other field with same name because you can see in fiddle it  works.

Comment: @Swati, I have updated the html snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran trial and error methods in my html file, and observed that when I removed below 3 lines, capturing values from dropdown worked.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
```

So, I checked the footer html, I had added the bootstrap 5 js bundle cdn link for navbar. I removed the bootstrap link, and it worked!

And regarding the said error is worth knowing, new learning! Hope this will help for others as well as this can be a case for such error.