# definition of dropdown() in semantic ui library

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Where is dropdown() defined in the library of semantic ui?

This question is needed as I want to figure out the solution to this question [Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626735/uncaught-typeerror-no-method-named-get-value-get-values-using-semantic-ui-f)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: No method named "get value" - get values using semantic ui for Multiple Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626735/uncaught-typeerror-no-method-named-get-value-get-values-using-semantic-ui-f)

Comment: No, infact I am the asker of the question you mentioned. but I found the issue observed in that question. Despite I still want to know answer to current question.